# How can I create SSL certificate on my local machine for Sitecore websites?

Tags: sitecore-client

How can I create SSL certificate on my local machine for Sitecore websites so that if I bind it to that Sitecore website in IIS, browser should show it as a secure site?

Right now I created my SSL certificates using below command

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName Sitecore.Tracking.Processing.Service -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My

Export-PfxCertificate -cert Cert:\LocalMachine\My\7777FB6C0248FD1D33D9D2F9D7A4828173DB13C6 -FilePath "C:\certificates\Sitecore.Tracking.Processing.Service.pfx" -Password $password
```

But browser giving warning for certificate and if I accept that certificate warning, then browser show my site but mark it as "Not Secure"?

[image]

Comment: can you make sure you have installed it in Trusted Root Certification Authorities?

Comment: Yes, its in Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Comment: If it is in Trusted Certification Authorities, can you make sure that you have selected the correct certificate from the IIS website binding? Also try to run the website is a private window. It should work

Answer (score 4):

You can download for this my GIST https://gist.github.com/x3mxray/0e4805002de6f43f5732c44f5de23d23

Extract files and change **folderRoot**, **CertificateName**, **CertificatePassword** in `install.ps1` and run it:

```
# Path to this folder
$folderRoot = "C:\temp\install_iis_certificate"

$installParams = @{    
    Path = "$folderRoot\parameters.json"
    CertificateName = "sitecore.tracking.collection.service"
    CertificatePassword = "b"    
}

Push-Location $folderRoot

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @installParams *>&1 | Tee-Object install.log

Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 3):

From Sitecore 9 onwards, Sitecore deliver `createcert.json` which is a Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF) configuration which supports multiple versions of Windows (Server).

Run it like so:

`scinst c:\path\to\createcert.json -CertificateName sitecore.tracking.processing.service`

You then need to go to IIS Manager, find your website, Bindings..., and then set the SSL certificate to the one which has just been created by SIF.